# consuming coupon code from list of coupon code?

Tags: database-design

I have a list of coupon code. Whenever a user x perform a set of action I want to assign a coupon code to him from this list.

I am thinking of following solution:

**Table structure**

```
Coupon_id
Customer_Id default null
```

**Flow will be:**

```
Fetch coupon_id where customer_id is current customer id
Else Set customer_id to first coupon_id where customer_Id is null.
Fetch coupon_id where customer_id is current customer id
```

What will be best way to achieve this?
One way I am thinking is blocking read on db. But that will not scale.

Comment: Have you looked at using a sequence for this? http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/statements_6015.htm

Comment: maybe you should try something like `select * from (select c.*, rownum from coupon c where customer_id is null) where rownum = 1 for update skip locked`. This `FOR UPDATE SKIP LOCKED` is important it will lock just some rows, but not the whole table.

Comment: @Donal yes. I am not able to get how sequence will help in this case?
As cupon code are pre generated.